# Speeding up hat matrices like $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ (projection matrices) and other aspects of custom-built estimator when software runs out of memory

Tags: estimation, estimators, computational-statistics

Is there a way to speed up $Z(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'$ type matrices? I am implementing the expression below directly using a matrix language and my program frequently crashes while if I run OLS on them using a pre-fabricated command, it is not an issue.

Is there a tip you guys might have to compute these matrices efficiently?

The goal here (but that is just an aside) is to implement the following estimator
\begin{eqnarray}
(X' P X - \sum_{i=1}^{n} P_{ii} X_{i}X_{i}' - \alpha X'X)^{-1} (X' P_Z y - \sum_{i=1}^{n} P_{ii} X_{i} y_{i} - \alpha X' y)
\end{eqnarray}
Now, $\alpha$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $(\overline{X}'\overline{X})^{-1} (\overline{X}' P_Z \overline{X} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} P_{ii} \overline{X}_{i} \overline{X}'_{i})$ where $\overline{X} = [y,X]$.

I am pretty confident that once I have found an efficient way to compute the projections, I can easily implement the rest easily.

Thanks so much!

Comment: The matrix $X'X$ is symmetric which can be used to speed up the inverse computation (e.g. compute Cholesky decomposition, then use it to compute the inverse). There is not much to do to speed up the matrix product ; first compute $X(X'X)^{-1}$, then $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ (you know that it is symmetric so you can compute only e.g. the lower triangular part).

Comment: what do you mean 'implementing them verbatim'?

Comment: "from scratch" I guess :D

Comment: Do you need the entire hat matrix for anything in particular? Or are you only after part of it (such as the diagonal)? The regression program you use may already calculate the QR decomposition, which may be useful if you can get it.

Comment: yes by verbatim, I meant that I take the expression on paper and coded it up exactly as is.

Comment: I actually need the entire thing and then the main diagonal as well. How would a QR decomposition work?

Comment: If you have and agree to use some in-built function solving systems of linear equations you may notice that `solve(A,B)` is `inv(A)*B` but is faster.

Comment: If you need the entire thing then you already have the main diagonal. Is it crashing on the inversion step? or after that? What do you use the entire thing to do?

Comment: @Glen_b The error is in the computation of the projection namely Runtime error: out of memory
Runtime error occurred in vanproj (12), call trace: I will now investigate whether it's just the inversion.

Comment: Hirek, I think it makes more sense to take your question back to where it was when it got its two answers, which deal fairly well with a perfectly good question, and then to ask a new question which reflects more nearly your actual problem. [It's not necessary to make any actual edits to your question to achieve that, you can simply roll it back in the edit history.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using QR decomposition (which ought to be available if you already have calculated the regression):

Let $X$ have $n$ rows and $p$ columns and be of full column rank.

$H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$

$=QR(R'Q'QR)^{-1}R'Q'$

$=QR(R'R)^{-1}R'Q'$

But if $R_1$ is the first $p$ rows of $R$ then $R'R=R_1'R_1$

$=QR(R_1'R_1)^{-1}R'Q'$

Now let $Q=(Q_1,Q_2)$ where $Q_1$ is the first $p$ columns of $Q$. Then $QR=Q_1R_1$.

$=Q_1R_1R_1^{-1}(R_1')^{-1}R_1'Q_1'$

$=Q_1Q_1'$

Where $Q_1$ is $n\times p$.

So if you have the QR decomposition of $X$, then the hat matrix is fairly simple.

Note that some regression programs will give $Q_1$ automatically. [It's also possibly that a regression program will have performed pivoting. That shouldn't impact the calculation of the hat matrix though.]

Comment: Does QR work for non-square matrices as well? @Glen_b

Comment: What do you mean "work" -- which matrix is non-square? In regression, when we take $X=QR$, we have $X$ is nxp, $Q$ is nxn, and $R$ is nxp but upper triangular (so only the top pxp part is nonzero).

Comment: X is n by k (as is usual in regression analysis) so X'X is a square.

Comment: Yes, absolutely that works!

Comment: I've just seen the update to your question; there may well be additional improvements that could be made.

Comment: Well that would of course be even more wonderful! If you could help me a little I would then reword the question to include asking for tips on how to best implement this estimator so that other SE users can see it in search as well. @Glen_b

Comment: I don't follow what's going on there, however; it simply looks like there's probably more opportunities to do things better.

Comment: Well I think the Achilles heel of this estimator is the projection issue which is nicely taken care of by your QR response. The eigenvalue thing is another thorny issue but the matrix language I use has a function for solving symmetric eigenvalue problems.

Comment: If you don't already have the QR, but need eigenvalues, you might actually consider whether you can do what you need with the SVD as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Hmm ok how are eigenvalues again related to singular values? The square root I believe?

Comment: The nonzero singular values are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues, I believe.  ... oh actually, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), which says the same thing.

Comment: THanks so much @Glen_b yeah I have posted the question in altered form here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139983/efficient-implementation-of-this-estimator-when-software-runs-out-of-memory by the way! :)

Comment: there must be a mistake somewhere I cannot get it to work neither Matlab nor in the other language I am using.

Comment: I am using a program that insists on pivoting manually and I don't quite understand how to pivot. Can you perhaps help me with that? @Glen_b

Comment: Is QR cheaper to compute than Cholesky?

Comment: I am very happy that people upvote this but please see my comment that it is still missing some information about pivoting.

Comment: @Elvis Actually, I believe the QR itself is more expensive than Cholesky ... but the subsequent calculation of the hat matrix is cheap, and it's considerably more widely used for regression since it's more stable. The question as it stood when I answered it implied the problem was being run after a regression.

Comment: @Hirek What kind of pivoting is being used? [Column pivoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Column_pivoting)? Or something else? [Having already changed from a simple regression question about a hat-matrix to something quite different, it now seems to be moving from a statistical problem to a software problem (*I don't understand how to make a particular piece of software do something*). It should probably roll back to where question and answers corresponded.]

Comment: Or is it using an implicit-Q algorithm as described [here](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter3.pdf)?

Comment: OK for the stability of QR. I think OP wants to implement the regression by himself, and is using an existing implementation for benchmark, but that his aim is to be able to do everything by himself.

Comment: Concerning pivoting... are you sure your matrix has full column rank ?

Comment: @Glen_b yes that document on the implicit q-algorithm may be it. The QR decomposition in matlab and my other software gives me Q and R output that simply does not reproduce a harmless projection matrix calculated the brute-force way. Therefore, I had been wondering how to implement this by column pivoting given that one of the packages I was using actually returned a matrix P that described as  2 x n matrix (where original matrix is m by n), the first row holds the permutation matrix P', the second row holds the interchange permutations. I believe I need to incorporate these somehow

Comment: Hirek If it's just a permutation matrix you're worried about, you can easily invert the permutation operation (you don't need to physically shift the decomposition - which is expensive - you just work out which parts to use when you calculate with it)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the SVD. E.g., since
$$
    X = U\Sigma V^T,
$$
then
$$
    (X^T X)^{-1} = (V\Sigma^2 V^T)^{-1} = V\Sigma^{-2} V^T,
$$
and thus
$$
    X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T = U I_r U^T = U_r U_r^T,
$$
where $I_r$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix with $r\leq n$ ones on the diagonal (upper part), and $n-r$ zeros on the lower diagonal, where $r$ is the rank of $X$.

This will likely speed up your computation.

Comment: I doubt it.The SVD is **not** a cheap computation.

Comment: Thanks @TommyL but I cannot quite follow your derivation. Is the last one an equality of the entire projection matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've updated the answer to make this clear. @Elvis is right, though, the SVD is something like $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$, so it is not cheap, but if you repeatedly need to project, you may gain a lot. In particular if $n<<p$ or $p<<n$, you can save greatly. Note also that $UI_r U^T$ corresponds to selecting the $r$ first columns of $U$ and compute $U_rU_r^T$.

Comment: @Tommy I think QR is also $O(n^3)$; I don't think any stable algorithm for computation of $X(X'X)X'$ will be of faster leading term than that; the only difference may be the factor out the front. Given the way the question is written now, this might turn out to be a better choice.

Comment: You’r right, the asymptotic complexity is the same for all these methods. It must take into account $p$ and $n$. Computing $X'X$ is $O(p^2n)$, inverting it is $O(p^3)$, computing $X(X'X)^{-1}$ is $O(np^2)$, and multiplying again by $X'$ is $O(np^2)$ too. So finally the complexity is $O(np^2)$. It is the same for SVD, and I think it is the same for QR (at least if you need only the $p$ first columns of Q).

So, who’s doing a benchmark? :)